What's alternative of HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError in new Polly version?
I am trying to upgrade Polly to v8, re-writing policies to utilize new ResiliencePipiline. At couple of places I am using HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
 HttpPolicyExtensions
                .HandleTransientHttpError()
                .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)));

Looking at the source code I've endup with something like this:
ResiliencePipelineBuilder<HttpResponseMessage>()
            .AddRetry(new RetryStrategyOptions<HttpResponseMessage>()
            {
                ShouldHandle = new PredicateBuilder<HttpResponseMessage>()
                    .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
                    .HandleResult(response => response.StatusCode >= HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout),
                MaxRetryAttempts = 3,
                DelayGenerator = static opt => ValueTask.FromResult((TimeSpan?)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, opt.AttemptNumber)))
            })
            .Build();


Did my post answer your question? If so, can you please mark it as the answer? If not, then do you have further questions?

Yes, it answers the question. I meant to keep it open for some time if there will be any better way or an exsiting extension. Thank you for help

In case of V8 there is no such extension like HandleTransientHttpError. On the other hand it provides two sets of strategies: AddStandardResilienceHandler and AddStandardHedgingHandler. Both pipelines consist of 5 well-configured strategies.

Yeah, but I've tried to keep it with the same behaviour as it was before

Yes, that looks good. If you want to have a bit more performant version then you can use switch expression instead of PredicateBuilder
var options = new RetryStrategyOptions<HttpResponseMessage>
{
    ShouldHandle = static args => args.Outcome switch
    {
        { Exception: HttpRequestException } => PredicateResult.True(),
        { Result.StatusCode: HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout} => PredicateResult.True(),
        { Result.StatusCode: >= HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError } => PredicateResult.True(),
        _ => PredicateResult.False()
    }
};

Please also note here the usage of static anonymous functions.

Update #1
This could be easily extracted into a util method to embrace reusablity.
public static class PollyUtils
{
  public static ValueTask<bool> HandleTransientHttpError(
    Outcome<HttpResponseMessage> outcome)
    => outcome switch
    {
        { Exception: HttpRequestException } => PredicateResult.True(),
        { Result.StatusCode: HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout} => PredicateResult.True(),
        { Result.StatusCode: >= HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError } => PredicateResult.True(),
        _ => PredicateResult.False()
    };
}

